# How to run a GAS Calendar function from a different Gmail account (not owner) in web app to retrieve upcoming event information?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm working on a Google web app which will display the upcoming event from the user's Google calendar.

I followed below instructions and managed to log the information which retrieves it from my Google calendar event.

https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/apps-script

However, the main web app is managed by a different admin account which I embedded the function.

When opening the web app, the event information was retrieved from the admin calendar account.

How do I dynamically change this so that, it will display the user's Gmail calendar information instead.
Where should I put the user's info(data/gmail account info) in the code below? (Let's assume that the user has already enabled the Google Calendar API and given permission to access)

```
function listUpcomingEvents() {
  var calendarId = 'primary';
  var optionalArgs = {
    timeMin: (new Date()).toISOString(),
    showDeleted: false,
    singleEvents: true,
    maxResults: 1,
    orderBy: 'startTime'
  };
  var response = Calendar.Events.list(calendarId, optionalArgs);
  var events = response.items;
  if (events.length > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
      var event = events[i];
       var eventId = event.getId().split("@")[0];
       var when = event.start.dateTime;
      if (!when) {
        when = event.start.date;
      }
      var hangoutLink = Calendar.Events.get(calendarId, eventId).hangoutLink;
     // Logger.log (" Event: " + event.summary + when +", link: " + hangoutLink); 
       Logger.log('%s (%s)', event.summary, when, hangoutLink);
      return 'Upcoming Event : ' + event.summary + ' on ' + when + ' @ ' + hangoutLink
    }
  } else {
     Logger.log('No upcoming events found');
     return 'No upcoming events found'
  }
}
```

Comment: From `However, the main web app is managed by a different admin account which I embedded the function.`, in your situation, are you are the owner of the Web Apps and can you manage it? If you can do it, can I ask you about the settings of `Execute the app as:` and `Who has access to the app:` for the Web Apps?

Comment: @Tanaike I have access to the admin account because I'm the one who is managing it. Currently the Execute the app as: is  "the main admin account" and the Who has access to the app: is "Anyone within the organization (our company)".

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your case, are there other options except for `the main admin account` in`Execute the app as:`?

Comment: @Tanaike the other option is "User accessing the web app". I changed to this option and it works perfectly now! 本当に助かりました！ありがとうございます！

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem thanks to @Tanaike 's help.

To solve this, go to "Publish" on the toolbar menu and choose "Deploy as web app. On the "Execute the app as:" field, choose "User accessing the web app" instead of the "Me" so that other users can run the function.